# Angular 6: Why can't I extend Services, without losing the functions of the ChildService?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, extends

I was building a bunch of angular REST-services for my frontend. There for I thought it would be a nice idea to have a mother class `BaseRestService`, which implements all the equal stuff like headers and some helper functions.

But when my child service extends the `BaseRestService`, I get `TypeErrors`, when I call some of the child functions. I tried debugging, and could see, that the child service is not of type `SomeExampleChildSerivce`, instead it is of type `BaseRestService`. Can someone explain this behavior or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Below you can see the code of my `BaseRestService` and an `ChildService`:

BaseRestService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export abstract class BaseRestService {
  headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `JWT ${this.authService.getToken()}`
  });

  constructor(
    public httpClient: HttpClient,
    public logger: LoggingService,
    public authService: AuthenticationService,
  ) { }

  public refreshToken(): void {
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `${this.authService.getToken()}`
    });
  }
}
```

ChildService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DimensionService extends BaseRestService{
  private url: string = `${BASE_URL}/dimensions`;

  constructor(
    public httpClient: HttpClient,
    public logger: LoggingService,
    public authService: AuthenticationService,
  ){
    super(httpClient, logger, authService);
  }

  get(url: string): Observable<DimensionAttribute> {
    return this.httpClient.get<DimensionAttribute>(url, { headers: this.headers })
  }

  list(url?: string, page = 0, size = 20): Observable<Page<DimensionAttributeWrapper>> {
    if (!url) url = `${this.url}?page=${page}&size=${size}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<Page<DimensionAttributeWrapper>>(url, { headers: this.headers })
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but you could simple inject `BaseRestService` into the contructor of `DimensionService`

Comment: Okay, but I would be interesting why the extend is not working.

Comment: What error do you get exactly? And Which line gives you such error?

Comment: The error occurs in the component where I use the child services. I now have a workaround, so cannot tell you the exact error message but it was like this `TypeError: CildService <some function> is not a function`. The same error for every function of the child serveries, no matter which childservice. I couldn't call any function of the child, only the parent functions where callable.

Comment: I have injected the service like every other service, as a parameter in the constructor of the component.

Answer (score 1):

This is really not an Angular issue but a Typescript issue. I bet you have defined the injection on the consumers using the "BaseRestService" type, correct?

If you are doing that then you will not get access to the children methods.

In such a case, you may want to have an interface for the common methods in the children, and then have a factory produce the children for you based on some criteria. There are other injection tricks, but you get the idea.

Alternatively, you may want to do a mixin, which may accomplish what you want on a different fashion.

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem again. I could not see any difference in the code, so I updated angular from Version 6.1 -> 7.0 which fixed that issue.